R - Addition after modulo operation
Running the snippet D=1;for (j in 1:5){D=(D-1)%%4;print(D)} I get the expected outcome:
[1] 0
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 0

But when I add 1 to the result D=1;for (j in 1:5){D=((D-1)%%4)+1;print(D)}, it changes to:
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1

Why does this happen?
This is what I would expect:
D=1;for (j in 1:5){D=(D-1)%%4;print(D+1)}
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1

Edit:
The code chunks above were written in a compressed form in order to avoid a lengthy post. A properly styled R code should look like this:
D <- 1
for (j in 1:5) {
D <- (D - 1) %% 4
print(D)
}


Your D is stuck in between 0 and 1 when you update D  with D=((D-1)%%4)+1, that's why you got all 1s

General point: if you ever write code like this in a real project, then your colleagues will absolutely hate you for it. It's completely unreadable and incredibly error-prone (as evidenced by this very post). Indeed, if you revisit code like this yourself after 6 months, you will generally find it incredibly difficult to understand what logic you were trying to express.

@alanocallaghan thanks for your constructive feedback. I have edited the question to reflect your point.

The point was not "rewrite the code in this question to make it more readable", the point was "you should be aware of why this style of coding is broadly discouraged". The problem in the question is solved already, but if you continue writing code like this you'll find yourself frequently making similar mistakes

You initialize D with 1. When j is 0 and later, then you compute
D=((D-1)%%4)+1


D-1 is 1-1, which is 0
0%%4 is 0
0 + 1 is 1

therefore, when D is 1, then the formula above will yield 1, independently of j's value, since D only depends on its own previous value and whenever it was 1, the formula yields 1, hence D will never change. Instead, try this formula:
D=(D%%4)+1


if D was 0, then the result will be 1
if D was 1, then the result will be 2
if D was 2, then the result will be 3
if D was 3, then the result will be 4
if D was 4, the result will be 1
and so on
and so on

Since you want
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1

you will need to initialize D with 0, so the first result will be 1:
D=0;for (j in 1:5){D=(D%%4)+1;print(D)}

EDIT
The solution above provides 1 2 3 4 ... If, instead 1 4 3 2 1 ... is needed, then one can use (4-D)%%4 instead of D%%4 and initialize D with 2.

I think yours will give 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, rather than the desired 1, 4, 3, 2, 1

@ThomasIsCoding thanks for pointing it out, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Yes, it works well now, +1!

Fantastic work! Thank you for the explanation and for  the efforts you have put into your answer!

It returns you 1 every time because what you are doing is :
D = 1
In your loop :
j = 1 : D = ((D - 1) %% 4 ) + 1 wich do D = ((1 - 1) %% 4 ) + 1
wich is equal to 0 %% 4 + 1 = 1
So at the end of this execution you get the same value of D as in the beginning and you do that 4 other times.
So your value of D doesn't change.
(English isn't my first language but if you need more details I would be happy to give you more)

You just need to add two more lines, say D <- D + 1 and D <- D - 1 like below
D <- 1
for (j in 1:5) {
    D <- ((D - 1) %% 4)
    D <- D + 1
    print(D)
    D <- D - 1
}

and you will obtain
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 1

